# How do I do double X, N amount of times?

Tags: python, math

I'm learning python, and I am stuck on a project. I have tried many ways but haven't come even close yet.

I want to double X, N times.

So if I bet 5, I want it to double my bet N times. If I have lost my bet 5 times in a row, my bet should be doubled four times, resulting in a final bet of 80.

5 * 2 = 10

5 * 2 * 2 = 20

5 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 40

5 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 80

It might seem easier to do this math differently but I think this way would be the most fitting approach for this particular circumstance.

It would be great if someone could help me with the block that essentially functions as so:

bank = bank - (bet doubled N times)

Thanks to anyone willing to help :)

A new guy on the block,

Marshall

Comment: It's the simple formula `X * 2**N`

Comment: Well, I feel dumb... This doesn't reflect that the first bet doesn't count as a double or nothing, but this formula is perfect! I can just negate 1 from my formula, to give the the desired results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the results in between, e.g. 10, 20, etc, you should use a `for` loop, which runs `N` Times and doubles `X` each time. If you just need the final result, it's just `X*2**N`.